# Why does blogdown keep rebuilding RMarkdown files?

Tags: r, blogdown

I have a github pages website that has a blog that I update with blogdown. Everything works fine, I like blogdown a lot, but every time I use `build_site()` it re-builds `.Rmd` files that should not (at least to my understanding) be built again, given that I haven't changed anything in those files. This is not ideal, because sometimes things change (like tables I've scraped from the web) and I have to re-write the whole post again. Has anybody experienced anything similar? What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not follow the [recommended workflow](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html). You do not have to, but then you will have to read the documentation more carefully to understand [what `blogdown::build_site()` actually does](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html). The same question has been asked [on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/109).