# clarity on publishing drafts with Blogdown

Tags: r, blogdown

Could anyone clarify this for me? If I use `blogdown::build_site()`, blogdown will compile all the `.Rmd` files I have in the website directory, something I don't want (and I've asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814532/why-does-blogdown-keep-rebuilding-rmarkdown-files)).
This being the case, Yihui has recommended using `blogdown::serve_site()` ([here](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/109) and [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html) in the recommended workflow). However, `serve_site()` publishes draft posts, which I obviously don't want published yet.
Judging from [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html), it seems that something that works is `serve_site()` followed by `hugo_build()`. Is that the correct way to go about it, or am I missing something? Because when I do that, the draft posts don't disappear. Thanks for any suggestions.

*Edit*: I should mention that running `hugo_build()` by itself doesn't seem to publish any of the `.Rmd` posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [documentation on `blogdown::build_site()` and `serve_site()`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/local-preview.html):

- `build_site()` and `hugo_build()` do not build draft or future posts;
- `serve_site()` does.

Let me illustrate the differences with a table:

```
                build draft?    build Rmd?      build which Rmd?
----------------------------------------------------------------
build_site()      NO              YES             ALL
serve_site()      YES             YES             SINGLE (*)
hugo_build()      NO              NO              NONE

(*) Only build the modified Rmd.
```

If the combination you want is (1) do not build draft, and (2) build only the modified Rmd, there is not a single function to do this, but you can take two steps:

```
blogdown::build_site(local = TRUE, run_hugo = FALSE)
blogdown::hugo_build()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, Yihui. When I ran `hugo_build()`, some of my newer posts did not show up on the website. I did not want to use `build_site()` for reasons I mentioned in an earlier question. So the other option is to use `serve_site()`, like you mentioned on Github. When I did that, however, the draft posts get published (I understood that `serve_site()`did that). So my confusion came about because of this -- am I doing something wrong? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'm confused by your confusion: do you want to publish draft posts or do you not? If you do, `serve_site()`; if you do not, `hugo_build()`. I'm afraid I cannot offer a better answer.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm not explaining it well. It seemed that `hugo_build()` was not compiling any `.Rmd` -- I had to then use `serve_site()`. I'm going to double-check what I did during the coming weekend and make sure I'm not making some dumb mistake. If I am, I apologise for wasting your time, and if I'm not, I'll be back! :-)

Comment: Your confusion is clear to me now. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Yihui. Just one question before I promise to stop bugging you: given that I can't use `build_site()` (old scripts that give errors now for various reasons; I also don´t want to rebuild everything every time), and that I don't want drafts to be published, do you have plans for blogdown to have an option that builds the `.Rmd` files but a) does not build drafts, and b) does not re-build old `.Rmd` files? It seems to me that none of `serve_site()`, `hugo_build()` or `build_site()` do what I'm looking for. In your table, it would be 'NO', 'YES', 'Only the modified Rmd'.

Comment: Exactly the clarification I was looking for! Thanks.